# C program to convert decimal to binary using AND bitwise operator

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have seen this code to convert decimal to binary using AND bitwise operator,and put the resulting binary number in an array to iterate over it later .since I'm new to C , I couldn't visualize the code

For example if we have number (13) in decimal, which equals (1101) in binary ... what exactly happens inside this for loop ?!

[image: C program to convert decimal to binary using AND bitwise operator]

Comment: Please do not post screenshot of code (text).

Comment: If you haven't use a debugger before, now is a good time to learn how to. With a debugger you can step through code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. Doing this you can see exactly what happens in the code.

Comment: OK, I've answered your question below... but the instruction inside the loop is so trivial that I wonder why you don't understand it yourself.

Comment: There is nothing here that converts decimal to binary. The code converts binary to an ASCII representation of binary.

Comment: @user6060561 .... I couldn't understand that because I don't see when the decimal number (say 13) gets converted to binary (1101)  ? if the binary size = 4 , will the compiler see the first iteration as (( 1101 & 1 << 3 ) ? '1' : '0' ) and then put the result in binary [0]  ? if so ... why is  ( << i ) used , not ( >> i ) ?!

Comment: There is no decimal number here. The value 13 is supplied in the `int` parameter `n`, which is already binary. Nothing is converted. Only the zoning bit is changed.

Comment: The decimal number isn't converted to binary. The binary number is converted to a character array.

Comment: @Some programmer dude ... thanks I will try the GDB

Comment: @user6060561 ... so the function already takes a binary number, not a decimal one , and puts it into array ?

Comment: `1 << i` creates a bit mask to test the bits of n consecutively.

Comment: @Ahmed Safwat Yes, the function receives n as an int, so it's obviously a binary value. "Decimal" is a representation of a number in the base-10 number format. The ternary conditional operator in the loop generates the decimal numbers, depending on one selected bit of n.

Comment: @user6060561 There are no decimal numbers here anywhere. Only binary, in zoned or unzoned representations. If there was any decimal anywhere the code would be full of 10s.

Answer (score 2):

The loop masks off one bit of n and writes '0' or '1' to the char buffer, depending on its state, starting with the most significant bit.

Comment: Since this code makes heavy use of implicit operator precedence, maybe some additional parentheses will help: `binary[pos-i] = (n & (1 << i)) ? '1' : '0';`

Comment: Help what? The compiler doesn't need redundant parentheses, and neither should the programmer.

Comment: Help readability. Frankly, omitting the parentheses here makes the statement much harder to understand.

Comment: Harder to understand for those who don't know the precedence rules. It always seems to be other people. I haven't encountered this mythical programmer since 1982 myself.

Comment: @EJP Well, I'm programming C/C++ for decades now, and still I'm thankful if a programmer cares to add "redundant" parentheses. I know the precedence rules, but my eyes catch the associations easier when there are parentheses, sorry. I'm glad to read that you don't need them.

Comment: I'm programming C for 3.5 decades, and its successors for just about as long as possible, and other things for another decade, and I've encountered an operator precedence problem/misunderstanding exactly once. It has always seemed to me that programmers are unduly dismissive, if not actually patronising, about each others' capabilities in this area. BODMAS or whatever you want to call it is taught in grade 3. Is it really so quickly forgotten?

Comment: It's not just BODMAS here. We've got a logical operator, a shift, and a ternary conditional. Especially the conditional can yield surprising results when its operands are expressions without parentheses. I'm quitting this useless discussion now...

Comment: In 19.. in my first programming experience, tutor said 'redundant brackets that make the line easier to understand are fine'.  I don't want my brain to be misused as a language parser - it's better off designing my overall system.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop it will check the each bit , wheather it is set or clear. if bit is set it will write '1' in array at the respective index or if bit is clear then it will write '0' in array at respective index.